# How to Convert DateTime to String?

Tags: php, string, datetime

I have an array of DateTime objects and need to use them as strings in a function call. I have tried casting it like `$string_datetime = (string)$myDateTimeObject;` but that doesn't work. Searching has been unfruitful as well, as most people are asking how to convert a string to DateTime instead.

My Code:

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$end_date = new DateTime();
$end_date = $end_date->modify('+1 day');

// Add time range to request
$request['time_range'] = Array ( 'start' => $start_date,
                                 'end'   => $end_date);
```

When calling a function which expects a string (it's an API call) I receive this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

What's the correct way of converting/extracting a string from a DateTime object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Comment: Damn. I can't believe I missed that! Thanks.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but RTFD: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: Seems like an oversight that `DateTime` can't be implicitly cast to string.  Personally, I use a wrapper class that extends it and adds a `__toString()` method (which uses `DateTime::format()`).  Still should be native functionality, IMO.

Comment: @drrcknlsn so you're saying that [PHP is an imperfect language?](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) Well, I _never!_ `</sarcasm>`

Comment: @MattBall: Of course PHP is an imperfect language - as are all other languages.  PHP just gets a bad wrap because of all the legitimate, yet *completely trivial* mistakes that were made in the past that have not yet been fixed due to backwards-compatibility issues (e.g. inconsistent argument order, function naming, and so on).

Comment: @Drrcknlsn I think the fact that you can extend it to add a string casting function is perfectly fine.  There are so many ways to output a date that I feel the only way they'd know how you wanted to set the output would be some unintuitive things such as setting a static DateTime class variable, and I feel relying on php.ini settings would be a terribly sad idea =p.  The forced extension to have a `__toString()` was a clean decision by the devs, and it allows you to DRY the implementation based on your own needs.  I mean, what do you expect to happen when calling `__toString()` arbitrarily?

Comment: @Anther:  The intelligent choice would have been to output the ISO standard format by default (`Y-m-d\TH:I:SZ` or whatever).  Extending it to override this would still be possible, but not _required_, and it's an international standard without bias.  They could have even made it configurable through `php.ini`.

Comment: @drrcknlsn When I was going to originally post that I think that having it set in php.ini would be a nightmare.  But I agree, it'd make working directly with db's and such more convenient.

Comment: Recommended lecture: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/